# Erlang a special value doule quote

Tags: erlang, double-quotes

When i run my program,a error hanppened, and when i look into the log, appears this   {k,3108,"s"},{k,3109,"}, how can a one double quote as a varible's value.

Comment: Could you edit your post and show the entire error message?

Comment: Give more info about your error. Maybe is it atom? `is_atom(''). return true`

Comment: Sorry for a vague question,now a post the screenshot.I've tested,and make sure not a  atom ''.

Answer (score 2):

In the text font it is a little hard to see exactly what you actually got in the log but I am guessing it is:

```
{k,3108,"s"},{k,3109,''}
```

The first true double quotes make an Erlang *string* (which is really a list of integers) while the second is actually a pair of `'` which is the quote character for *atoms*. In this case it is the atom with the empty name which is allowed. This is what @shk indicated.

But without more information from you it is really hard to give a proper answer.

Comment: Actully, I am sure is a " rather than ''.Now i mentioned that is double quote's  ascii code 34,for it print some special character like #, ☉ .but i can't actully print a " when use a erl emulater.

Comment: If the second `"` really is a `"` instead of `''` then there needs to be a matching `"`. No, erlang will not print a `"`, it would instead print 34 as there is no char type.